# D3 and jQuery - Ajax success function fill color change is not applied to D3 SVG

Tags: jquery, ajax, svg, d3.js

I've created a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/UEjKbTWp) with the code for this module in case anyone wants the full source for reference.

I have a map of the US drawn as a SVG graphic with D3.  There are several event listeners bound to each path, but only one relies on jQuery.  When a click event occurs on the map, a D3 tooltip is created with

line 39 of the pastebin

```
buttonTemplate : "<div id = 'tooltip_template'>" + 
            "<div class = 'county_data'></div>" +
            "<img src = '/static/images/delete.png' width = '28' height = '28' class = 'delete_logo' id = 'close_tooltip' />" +
            "<div id = 'no_client_message'></div>" +
            "<button id = 'add_prospective_market' class = 'tooltip_button'>Prospective Market</button>" +
            "<button id = 'add_market' class = 'tooltip_button'>Market County</button>" +
            "<button id = 'remove_market' class = 'tooltip_button'>Remove Market</button></div>"
```

as a HTML DOM element.

The three buttons each have listeners assigned to them via event delegation on line 73:

```
$("body") 
        .on("click", "#add_market", function(){
            if (thisObj._currentCounty.color != thisObj._fillColors.market)
                marketHandler(0);
            else
                $("#no_client_message").text("Market button has been disabled");
        })
        .on("click", "#add_prospective_market", function(){
            if (thisObj._currentCounty.color != thisObj._fillColors.prospect)
                marketHandler(1);
            else
                $("#no_client_message").text("Prospective market button has been disabled");
        })
        .on("click", "#remove_market", function(){
            marketHandler(2);
        })
```

and I have the handler function defined on line 211 as

```
//executes ajax post request to add a new client-county relationship.  Type is 0 for
//new market, 1 for new prospective market and 2 for remove this client-county relationship
var marketHandler = function(type){
    $.ajax({
        url : "marketHandler/",
        type : "POST",
        data : {"data" : JSON.stringify({
                            "client" : thisObj._currentClient.id,
                            "county" : thisObj._currentCounty.id,
                            "type" : type
                        })
                },
        dataType : "json",
        success : function(results){
            if (results.success == "true"){

            /*
                console.log("Market handler type: " + type);

                var fillColor = "";

                if (type == 0)
                    fillColor = thisObj._fillColors.market;

                else if (type == 1)
                    fillColor = thisObj._fillColors.prospect;

                else
                    fillColor = thisObj._fillColors.neutral;

                d3.selectAll($("#" + thisObj._currentCounty.id))
                    .style("fill", fillColor);

                closeTooltipHandler();
            */
                //hack to get the fill color change to apply.  There is some conflict going
                //on between the jquery and d3 event handlers.  While the function executes,
                //the change of the fill is not applied on success.
                thisObj._clientSelect.trigger("change");
            } else
                alert(results.message);
        }
    })
}
```

My issue is that while the Ajax function is successful and the `results.success == "true"` conditional is met, the color change normally executed via

```
d3.selectAll($("#" + thisObj._currentCounty.id))
  .style("fill", fillColor);
```

is never applied to the map.  Instead, my only solution at this time is to trigger a change event on the view's dropdown list.  While this works, it is unneccessarily complicated, as it neccessitates a redundant data fetch only to execute the recoloring operation.

I originally thought it was due to being nested within the Ajax function, so I made the success function change to

```
var fillColor = "";
var colorChange = false;

$.ajax({
  ...
  ...
  success : function(results) {
    if (results.success == "true){
      colorChange = true;

      //get fillColor hex value
    }
  }
});

if (colorChange){
  d3.selectAll($("#" + thisObj._currentCounty.id))
    .style("fill", fillColor);
}
```

but this did not work either.

Comment: It sounds like a scoping issue within your ajax success callback. I've been working with D3 and Backbone and I know the scope gets lost sometimes. You could try wrapping that selectAll in a function like updateColor( colorStr). Above the ajax block, you could add: var scope = this; and then you would be able to call scope.updateColor( fillColor ) within the success block.

Comment: @headwinds, I tried that, only to get a scope.updateColor is not a function warning.

Answer (score 0):

As headwinds suggested in the comments, it was indeed a scoping issue, and I resolved it by using an anonymous function in the success callback.  My success handler is now

```
success : function(results){
  if (results.success == "true"){

    if (type == 0)
      fillColor = thisObj._fillColors.market;

    else if (type == 1)
      fillColor = thisObj._fillColors.prospect;

    else
      fillColor = thisObj._fillColors.neutral;

    closeTooltipHandler();

    //need anonymous function to resolve scope issue between D3 and jQuery
    (function(thisObj, fillColor){
      d3.selectAll($("#" + thisObj._currentCounty.id))
        .style("fill", fillColor)
    })(thisObj, fillColor);

  } else
    alert(results.message);
}
```